# Using IoC to inject a Node2BeanProcessor in my Magnolia module instead of using Components

Tags: java, guice, jcr, magnolia

I have a standard Magnolia module that I've implemented as a Spring MVC REST client. In this module, I am trying to retrieve a JCR node and use `Node2BeanProcessor` to transform the `Node` object into my custom bean. Code below:

```
@Repository
public class JcrRepo() {
    @Inject
    public Node2BeanProcessor node2Bean;

    public MagicWord getMagicWord(String key) {
        Session session = LifeTimeJCRSessionUtil.getSession("magic");

        Node theNode = session.getNode("/magicWords/" + key);

        return node2Bean.toBean(theNode, MagicWord.class);
    }
}
```

When I run this, I encounter a `NullPointerException` for the variable `node2Bean`. Which means it wasn't injected properly. However, I am able to do this:

```
node2Bean = Components.getComponent(Node2BeanProcessor.class);
```

The `Components.getComponent()` javadoc states: "Returns a component from the currently set ComponentProvider. Consider using IoC to inject the component instead." Which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Note that I have not done any Guice configuration as I'm looking for a way to leverage on Magnolia's already initialized Guice context to grab my objects.

Is there a better way to do injection than this, or have I done anything wrong or skipped a step?

Appreciate the help.

P.S. For now I've implemented a hacky way to use this in Spring IoC:

```
@Bean
public Node2BeanProcessor node2Bean() {
    return Components.getComponent(Node2BeanProcessor.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include your Guice module?

Comment: @durron597 actually I haven't configured anything in Guice. I'm looking for a way to use the Guice context that's already in the main Magnolia project. Will try to edit.

Answer (score 1):

(Working with Magnolia 4.5) I use `@Inject` for `Node2BeanProcessor` in a class implementing `info.magnolia.module.ModuleLifecycle`:

```
public class MyModule implements ModuleLifecycle {
    @Inject
    private Node2BeanProcessor node2BeanProcessor;

    @Override
    public void start(ModuleLifecycleContext moduleLifecycleContext) {
        ...
        getNode2BeanProcessor().toBean(someNode);
        ...
    }
}
```

Maybe your `NullPointerException` comes from `theNode`? Have you verified that `theNode` is not `null`?

Another guess is that it could be a lifecycle issue. From what I remember, `Components.getComponent()` works in situations where `@Inject` does not (in Magnolia).

Finally: Your instance variable should definitely be private.

Answer (score 1):

If `JcrRepo` is not instantiated by Guice then Guice also won't be available to inject the `Node2BeanProcessor` field. Mixing Spring and Guice IoC containers can get confusing, so I tend to stick with Guice as that's what comes with Magnolia.